# How to add numbers from JTextField at arraylist?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextfield

It my first work with `swing`, help please.

```
//In this texfield should be an array of digits like this: 10, 5, 8, 1, 11
private JTextField  setATextField = new JTextField(10);
private JButton button = new JButton("Button");
//....
//....
public class UnionActionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        ArrayList<Integer> setA = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

How to add this digits in `arraylist`?
it must be like this:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField("10, 5, 8, 1, 11", 10);
setA.get(0) = 10;
setA.get(1) = 5;
setA.get(2) = 8;
//......
```

Comment: If you want to add together all the `int`s in an `ArrayList`, you can do `int sum; setA.forEach((elm) -> sum += Integer.intValueOf(elm));`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125296/how-to-sum-a-list-of-integers-with-java-streams

Comment: @Majora320 , Yes, i want add all int s in an arraylist from JTextField setATextField.
' public class UnionActionListener implements ActionListener {
       @ Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            ArrayList<Integer> setA = new ArrayL;ist<>();
            int sum;
            setA.forEach((Integer) -> sum+=Integer.valueOf(setATextField));'
It don't work.

Comment: If you had searched the site, there are plenty of posts on this topic. Flagging as a duplicate.