# Read a file and spit out the count of the words using HashMap and HashSet

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, hashset

This is my first experience in writing code using `HashMap` and `HashSet` and I am a little confused where to start from. I want to read a file and count the number of strings used but I have to do this using `HashMap` and `HashSet`.

Any ideas on where to start from?

So I will read the file and put the strings in an array and then read it from the array and putting them into a `HashSet`? Is this an idiotic idea?

The constraint is that The only `O(n)` operation in the program should be iterating through the text file.

Thank you for the contribution in increasing my knowledge ;)

Comment: You don't need a set, just a map (because the keys of a map are already in a set). You would want a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key which refers to the word is a string and the value an integer which is the count. So you read the file word by word and add the word to the map with a count of 1 if the key mapping doesn't exist in the map, or increment it by 1 if the key mapping exists.

Comment: Read a line in a loop, and for every word in the line increase its count in the frequency table.

Comment: How can i return this integer? or Should I store it in another variable and then return it?

Comment: @database thank you for the suggestions ^_^

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you too

Comment: @SaidaHoca my name is database now? lol answering you last question, you don't need to return anything, just set the map's value to what I said above.

Comment: *"Read a file and spit out ..."* - Don't teach your program to "spit".  It is unhygienic.  A polite program should always output things ... without unwanted saliva.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

first you read entire data from file and store in string object
now use `java.util.StringTokenizer` class .it will split up all words in token
now read all token one by one and check it like following
use word as Key and its frequency as value in `HashMap`

```
HashMap map=new HashMap();
HashSet set=new HashSet();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strObj);
String s;
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     s=st.nextToken();
    if(map.containsKey(s))
    {
        count=(Integer)map.get(s);
        count++;
        map.put(s,count);
        set.add(s);
    }
    else
    {
        map.put(s,count);
        set.add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Drop the set, it only stores redundant data (keyword maintainability). If you actually are in need for such a set, you can get it any time via `map.keySet();`.

Comment: thanx for refine my logic.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but can miss out the middle man (that array).

You can use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to store a map of string to count of string.
What you need your program to do is:

1. Read the next string from the file.
2. Check if that string exists in you `HashMap`:

   1. If it does exist, just grab the `Integer` that the `String` maps onto from the map, increment it, and put it back into the map.
   2. If it does not exist, put the `String` in the map with the `Integer` 1.
3. Repeat from step 1 until the file has been read.
4. Grab the value collection from the `HashMap` and store it using `Collection<Integer> counts = map.values();`
5. Sum the collection using streams `int sum = counts.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();`
6. Output the value of `sum`.

I'm sure you can figure out to convert that to code yourself! :)

---

You can find more info on `HashMap` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (check out the `values()` method), more info on `Stream` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), and more info on that funky bit of code from step 5 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125296/how-to-sum-a-list-of-integers-with-java-streams).

Comment: Integer is immutable, so you have to put a new instance into the map. This is why I used my own wrapper class in my answer...

Comment: @Aconcagua You're right, it is. I'll update my answer to make the process a little clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Sharad's answer: Reading from file...

```
// would loved to use Integer, but it is immutable...
class Wrapper
{
    public Wrapper(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int value;
}

HashMap<String, Wrapper> counts = new HashMap<String, Wrapper>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
while(scanner.hasNext())
{
    String token = scanner.next();
    Wrapper count = counts.get(token);
    if(count == null)
    {
        counts.put(token, new Wrapper(1));
    }
    else
    {
        ++count.value;
    }
}
scanner.close();
```

I varied sharad's algorithm a little, not having to calculate the hash value twice if the value is already in the map, and using generics saves you from having to cast.

If you need only the strings in the file as set, you get it via `counts.keySet();`.

Comment: thank u, I have a last question. Inside what class will the code you provided be in?

Comment: @SaidaHoca There are many options. If you do not want to do anything else in your program, you can have the Wrapper class as inner class of the one containing main and place the loop directly into the main method - iterating over the map directly afterwards to output the results. You can have the loop in a separate method (parallel to main), which would return the HashMap. Or you can create a separate class with Wrapper as inner class and the loop in a static method. Alternatively, the HashMap can be a member variable and the loop (including the scanner instance) placed in a non-static method.

Comment: I got what you said and I tried to do it but there is an error which says that can not resolve the get method :/

Comment: @SaidaHoca Oh, sorry, must be counts.get, of course... And before you stumble over yourself: If you use Wrapper as an inner class, you need to make it static if using in a static method (including main).

Comment: @SaidaHoca And we should close the scanner again.