# How to find the sum based on some property of objects from List of objects in Java 8 using stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects which contains the medium of transaction and transaction amount. I want to find the total amount for particular transaction.

For example- 
I have the following objects in list -

```
Credit card 10
Debit card 20
Credit card 30
Credit card 20
Debit card  20
Digital Wallet 30
Debit card 40
```

I want output like this -

```
Credit Card 60
Debit card 80
Digital Wallet 30
```

I want it to do using Java 8 stream. Can anyone please help!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I started with [How to sum a list of integers with java streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125296/how-to-sum-a-list-of-integers-with-java-streams) and got a basic example running, but required three lines (one for each group), I then used [Java 8 – Stream Collectors groupingBy examples](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/), which, if you read through all the examples will provide you with an "exact example" of what you are looking for - all in 10 minutes - and no, I'm not posting it - that's an adventure I won't rob you of ;)

Comment: I already tried - transaction.stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy()...). But, inside grouping by I was not able to map the transaction type of the transaction object using t -> t.getTransactionMedium()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so,

```
Map<String, Double> txAmountByMedium = transactions.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Transaction::getMedium, 
        Collectors.summingDouble(Transaction::getAmount)));
```

First group the transactions by their medium using `groupingBy` collector. Then use a downstream collector to sum the transaction amount for each group.