# How to find sum in Java 8 based on a property of an object

Tags: java, sum, double, java-stream

I have a class defined like this:

```
public class Item {

    String name;
    double price;
}
```

Now I have a list of Item objects, now I want to find total price for all the items. How can we do this in Java 8?

If the list is of simple integers then we have solution given here - [How to sum a list of integers with java streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125296/how-to-sum-a-list-of-integers-with-java-streams)

Comment: `listOfItems.stream().mapToDouble( Item::getPrice ).sum()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can map the `Item`s to their prices:

```
List<Item> items = ...;
double sum = items.stream().mapToDouble(Item::getPrice).sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use Double? It got methos `sum()` which might be a solution for you.

Example code:

```
class Entry {
    Double value;

    public Entry(Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

List<Entry> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Populate list
    exampleList.add(new Entry(10d));
}

Double sum = 0d;
for (Entry entry : exampleList) { //Sum up values
    Double.sum(sum, entry.value);
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

**EDIT**

Why you should not depend on wrapping primitives (Autoboxing) and declare Wrapper class directly

**tldr;**

*STORING VALUES IN PRIMITIVES, AND USING COLLECTION IS LESS EFFICENT THEN DECLARING VARIABLE AS WRAPPER CLASS IN 1ST PLACE*

As we can read in Java Documentation [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), each time you use `get()` or `set()` on collection using primitive, the Autoboxing or Unboxing will occur, greatly lowering performance.

> So when should you use autoboxing and unboxing? Use them only when there is an “impedance mismatch” between reference types and primitives, for example, when you have to put numerical values into a collection. It is not appropriate to use autoboxing and unboxing for scientific computing, or other performance-sensitive numerical code. An Integer is not a substitute for an int; autoboxing and unboxing blur the distinction between primitive types and reference types, but they do not eliminate it.

**Other pitfalls using Autoboxing**

- **Cashing of Wrapper Class**

As you can read in [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

According to this line, think what will be the output of

```
public class AutoboxingNotSoCool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("-129") == (Integer.valueOf("-129")));
        System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("100") == (Integer.valueOf("100")));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
false
true
```

**(Please not that you should *NEVER* compare two object's using `==`)**

- **You will need to manifestly declary number type**

Let's look at this little piece of code.

```
public class AutoboxingNotSoCool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Float manifestlyDeclaredVariable = 2F;

        System.out.println(manifestlyDeclaredVariable.equals(2));
        System.out.println(manifestlyDeclaredVariable.equals(2F));
    }
}
```

The result of this would be

```
false
true
```

And this is because 2 will be Autoboxed to Integer (2L will be Autoboxed to Long, 2F will be Autoboxed to Float)

Comment: Storing it as a `double` is cheaper and it should autoconvert (called ['autoboxing'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)) to a `Double` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, add accessor methods:

```java
public class Item {
    String name;
    double price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Then, loop through the `Item`s and add their `price`s together:

```java
double totalPrice = 0.0;
for (final Item item : itemList) {
    totalPrice += item.getPrice();
}
System.out.printf("The total price is $%.2f.\n", totalPrice);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for an answer in Java8 using streams, Mureinik has given that

Comment: Ahh, no problem.